# Pyramid Chameleon I18N not finding template files

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid, pylons, chameleon

I'm following  this recipe, with a small test project called i18n

[Chameleon I18N](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates/chameleon_i18n.html)

I've set up the message_extractors as follows:

```
message_extractors = { '.': [
    ( '**.py', 'lingua_python', None ),
    ( '**.pt', 'lingua_xml', None ),
    ]};
```

When I run the extract_messages  code, I don't get any templates processed:

```
../bin/python setup.py extract_messages -o locale/test.pot
    running extract_messages
    extracting messages from i18n/__init__.py
    extracting messages from i18n/models.py
    extracting messages from i18n/tests.py
    extracting messages from i18n/views.py
    extracting messages from i18n/scripts/__init__.py
    extracting messages from i18n/scripts/initializedb.py
    writing PO template file to locale/test.pot
```

Why are the template files skipped when they're in the source tree?

Answer (score 0):

That section of the cookbook is outdated: current versions of lingua no longer use Babel, or any configuration through setup.py/setup.cfg. You can use lingua's pot-create command to extract messages from your code and mpaltes instead. The [lingua page on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lingua) has a fair amount of documentation and examples for doing that.