# Lingua with Pyramids and Chameleon

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid, pylons, chameleon

i want to use lingua 3.10 for i18n in my pyramids 1.6 app, which uses chameleon templates. As far as I know, the [lingua helper script](https://github.com/wichert/lingua/blob/master/docs/examples/i18n.sh) should work out of the box, whereby only the path-variables of the script itself have to be edited.

Unfortunately nothing happens. As already answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249963/pyramid-chameleon-i18n-not-finding-template-files), the cookbook is out of date. So ... is there any small how-to?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had a non-valid html-file!